# Does using strings containing multiple words separated with whitespaces in select statements 'AS' yield any disadvantages?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

When working with SQL Statements in general you would usually encounter something like:

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS `rowCount` FROM `someTable`;
```

Now is there any disadvantage technical or style guide wise if we would write the query as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS `Row count` FROM `someTable`;
```

---

Or:

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) `rowCount` FROM `someTable`;
```

vs

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) `Row count` FROM `someTable`;
```

---

I'm asking specifically about **whitespaces** in the name we give the result column.

---

Could this maybe generate an issue when using this query within any programming language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you try to access the columns when you fetch them.

In PHP, if you fetch the rows into an object (rather than an associative array), the alias will become the object property. Accessing a property with a space in its name is not as convenient. Instead of

```
$row->rowCount
```

you would have to write:

```
$row->{"Row count"}
```

But the most common way to access columns in most MySQL APIs is using some kind of associative array or dictionary. In this case, there's not much difference between

```
$row['rowCount']
```

and

```
$row['Row count']
```

since you have to put the alias name in quotes either way.

Answer (score 1):

If you put whitespace into your identifiers, then you *must* delimit them every time you use them.

If you don't put whitespace in your identifiers, and also don't use punctuation characters, non-ASCII characters, and don't use [SQL reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html), then you have the option of using the identifer without delimiting it.